# For loops / Increment and Decrement

Tags: java

I'm trying to make variable **mark** to decrement by 5 instead of 1. I want position 0 to remain the default input and after to decrement by 5 each time goes around the loop.

So if i input mark as 82 , the output should be :

> (0)82; (1) 77; (2) 72 etc

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Late {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int mark;
        int numberOfDays;
        int counter = 4;

        Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Input mark");
        mark = scn.nextInt();

        System.out.println("Input number of days");
        numberOfDays = scn.nextInt();

        for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfDays; i++) {
            System.out.println("(" + i + ")" +  mark--);
        }                    
    }
}
```

Comment: `mark--` is the same as `mark -= 1` or `mark = mark  - 1`. I let you do the rest

Comment: can you tell us how you get the output please?

Answer (score 3):

You already know about assignment, why not just do the most obvious?

```
mark = mark - 5;
```

In fact, the postfix `--` and `++` operators are not the only way of manipulating the value of a variable. Even if they were, you could just write `mark--` five times.

In most C-like languages (and Java is no exception), you can shorten this to

```
mark -= 5;
```

But the first variant is perfectly fine, too.

Comment: Note that using `mark--` instead of `--mark` force you to do the assigment in a specific place ;)